# How to store data like text and images?

Tags: android

I'm pretty new to Android and I try to get into it by writing an App. It'll be a fitness app that also shows different kinds of exercises. For each exercise several data should be shown:

- name of the exercise
- pictures of how to perform it
- textual description of how to perform it
- muscles that are used
- level of difficulty

I'm not really sure how to store this data in the best way. The data never change and are only shown inside the app. I'm thinking about:

- using an XML file to store the information. e.g.

  ```
  <EXERCISE NAME>
    <PICTURES>
      <PICTURE>filepath_of_the_picture_1></PICTURE>
      <PICTURE>filepath_of_the_picture_2></PICTURE>
      <PICTURE>filepath_of_the_picture_3></PICTURE>
    </PICTURES>
  <DESCRIPTION></DESCRIPTION>
    ...
  </EXERCISE NAME>
  ```
- next option is to use an sqllite database. I never worked with the DB provided by Android. So I'm not really sure if this is a good option, since I also need to store the images. But it might make sense since I plan to use it for storing "links". E.g. An exercise can be added to a personal trainings plan. The connection between those two can be stored in the DB. There is much more like this. So what do you think?

Answer (score 2):

> The data never change and are only shown inside the app

So you can just use local resources like the `drawable` folder and `res/values/strings.xml` Why would you need some other kind of storage in this particular case?

Comment: If I use lots of images the size of the app increases. Since I plan to use videos in the future the app size will be much too big. So I'd like to have the option to load the videos e.g. seperately and integrate them on demand into the app.

Generally: it would be nice to have the assets like images and videos seperated from the app. This way an update could be provided that is only related to the data.

Comment: "integrate on-demand" - I guess you mean online loading? Since that's the only way you can do it. In that case you'll need to provide your app with a back-end that will respond to your app requests and send the data. As for storage, you could simply create a directory on SD and store your stuff there (you'd need to include the permission to read/write external storage into your Manifest file)